# Deadlock in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, transactions

I have a Webservice that receives a couple requests at nearly the same time.

If that happens the Transactions of the two requests deadlock and i have to rollback an rerun on of them.

```
        using (var context = new DbContext())
        using (var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
        {
                var subscription = context.Subscriptions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Provider == provider);
                if (subscription == null)
                {
                   */Insert*/
                }
                else
                {
                   /*Update*/
                }
                context.SaveInTransaction(null);
                dbContextTransaction.Commit();
                }
```

As i understand both of the Requests enter the Transaction and read the Subscriptions Table. By the time the are ready to commit, they are deadlocked because they can't insert values in a data range read by another transaction (IsolationLevel.Serializable).

If i don't make the TransactionLevel Serializeable, one of the Requests fails to meet the Unique constraints of the Provider Column and gets Rollbacked.

What should i do to prevent deadlocks?

Comment: You can use a `lock` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Comment: Either catch exception indicating unique violation and retry, or use raw sql to perform "upsert" (in sql server corresponding operation is MERGE) in one atomic operation. I'm not aware of other ways to handle that in EF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > If i don't make the TransactionLevel Serializeable, one of the Requests fails to meet the Unique constraints of the Provider Column and gets Rollbacked.

You can :

1) Handle the PK violation  / Deadlock and proceed to update the existing row.  Note you should use READ COMMITTED and handle the PK violation since you know that the session that gets the failure can proceed to update.  With SERIALIZABLE you can get a deadlock on either the INSERT or the UPDATE.

2) Use raw SQL with a lock hint to make one session wait for the other.

The correct lock hint is (UPDLOCK,SERIALIZABLE).  And the lock hint is *still required* if you use MERGE.  See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2013/02/25/why-is-tsql-merge-failing-with-a-primary-key-violation-isnt-it-atomic/

3) Call [sp_getapplock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql) at the beginning of the transaction to ensure only one session has the lock.  Note a CLR lock will only work if you have a single instance of your application.  For a client/server app, or a web farm a CLR lock will not work.

You can add a method to your DbContext something like:

```
public void GetAppLock(string lockName)
{
    this.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec sp_getapplock @name, 'exclusive'", new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@name",lockName));
}
```

Comment: Isn't just SERIALIZABLE enough? Why also updlock is needed?

Comment: UPDLOCK is required for SELECT, as SERIALIZABLE will use S locks otherwise.  For MERGE (or UPDATE) SERIALIZABLE is enough, as they already take U locks when reading, and you just need to add range locking for empty key ranges.

Comment: Ah, I though you mean that hints are required for merge specifically

Comment: I guess that calling `sp_getapplock` "at the beginning of the transaction" means: right *after* the `BeginTransaction` statement (otherwise it won't be scoped to that session).